# How can I replace duplicate strings with increasing order in T-SQL?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a single row table:

```
Id | Description
---------------
 1   #Hello#, Its 5 am. #Hello#, Its 9 am. #Hello# its 12 pm.
```

I want to replace these duplicate string `#Hello#` with an increasing order. I need output like

```
Id | Description
---------------
 1   #Hello#, Its 5 am. #Hello1#, Its 9 am. #Hello2# its 12 pm
```

Comment: I recommend normalizing your database so you can take advantage of the _relational_ capabilities of SQL server.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one,

```
DECLARE @V_STR      NVARCHAR(1000)  =   (SELECT [Description] FROM [Table1])
        ,@V_COUNT   INT =   0
        ,@V_TMP     NVARCHAR(100)   =   '#Hello#'
WHILE ((CHARINDEX(@V_TMP,@V_STR)) > 0)
BEGIN
    SELECT @V_STR = STUFF(@V_STR,(CHARINDEX(@V_TMP,@V_STR)),LEN(@V_TMP),'#Hello'+CAST(@V_COUNT AS NVARCHAR)+'#')
    SET @V_COUNT += 1
END
SELECT @V_STR
```